# Getting random time interval in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals

I need random interval time between 0 and (10 days and 5 hours).

My code:

```
select random() * (interval '10 days 5 hours')
from generate_series(1, 50)
```

It works like should, except a few strange results, like:

```
0 years 0 mons 7 days 26 hours 10 mins 1.353353 secs
```

The problem is 26 hours, it shouldn't be more than 23. And I never get 10 days, what I'd like to.

Comment: How do you plan to use this series?  Are you planning to use it with dates or timestamps?

Comment: I plan use it with timestamps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Intervals in Postgres are quite flexible, so hour values of greater than 23 do not necessarily roll over to days.  Use `jusify_interval()` to return them to the normal "days" and "hours"."

So:

```
select justify_interval(random() * interval '10 day 5 hour')
from generate_series(1, 200)
order by 1 desc;
```

will return values with appropriate values for days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

Now, why aren't you getting intervals with more than 10 days?  This is simple randomness.  If you increase the number of rows to 200 (as above), you'll see them (in all likelihood).  If you run the code multiple times, sometimes you'll see none in that range; sometimes you'll see two.

Why?  You are asking how often you get a value of 240+ in a range of 245.  Those top 5 hours account for 0.02% of the range (about 1/50).  In other words a sample of 50 is not big enough -- any given sample of 50 random values is likely to be missing 1 or more 5 hour ranges.

Plus, without `justify_interval()`, you are likely to miss those anyway because they may show up as 9 days with an hours component larger than 23.

Comment: This is a really great answer, maybe a +15 at some point.  You should stay away from Times Square tonight if possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Happy New Year!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select justify_hours(random() * (interval '245 hours'))
FROM generate_series(1, 50)
```

See [Postgres Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html) for an explanation of the justify_* functions.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use an interval of one hour, and then multiply by the random number between 0 and 1 coming from the series:

```
select random() * 245 * interval '1 hour'
from generate_series(1, 50);
```

I can see that the other answers suggest using `justify_interval`.  If you just want a series of intervals between 0 and 245 hours (245 hours corresponding to 10 days and 5 hours), then my answer should suffice.

Comment: The upvote is really curious.  This definitely does not address the concern about hours being greater than 23, not does it explain why intervals greater than 10 days might not be seen.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just ran my query and in fact generated one data point with 242 hours, which is greater than 10 days, so I don't really know what you're talking about.  Regarding the hours being "greater" than 23, this should not matter assuming the OP is just going to use these values to offset a timestamp.  I mean, adding `interval 48 hours` should be the same as `interval 2 days`, right?

Comment: . . My comment was directed toward the upvote, not the answer.  Whether relevant or not, the OP is specifically asking about hour values greater than 23 -- in fact, probably the reason the OP misses the 10+ days is because of how Postgres represents intervals.